# Getting the N76VZ subwoofer to work in Linux

Tags: laptop, audio, opensuse-12.2

I've got an ASUS N76VZ laptop with openSUSE 12.2 but I found that the subwoofer that came with the notebook doesn't work when I plug it in.

This sbwoofer is a special ASUS subwoofer plugged in with a smaller jack on the right side of the laptop. AFAIK N76VZ uses Intel hardware (it's powered by an i7) for both video and audio.

`lspci` returns, among all

```
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
```

In Windows 7, it works fine. I'm pretty sure that this is a driver issue, but I'm not very familiar with notebook audio in Linux. Also in Windows when I plug the sub in, a tray notification informs me "a jack has been inserted". This comes from the standard ASUS/Intel driver that came from drivers DVD (when I unpacked the notebook I first formatted it with vanilla Win&Linux)

Any help?

Comment: How does the subwoofer plug in?  Does sound work properly otherwise?

Comment: Subwoofer is plugged in in a non-standard yellow plug on right side of notebook. The rest of the sound works fine in Linux. I'll try to search for a few photos or videos about the sub

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aLwECXAVpE0 cable is on the right. It's slightly smaller than normal audio jacks, so it doesn't fit regular headphone jack

Comment: Do you see anything in the syslog when you plug it in?  I'm expecting not, if it's really just a funny audio jack.

Comment: In fact nothing. Updating question...

Comment: Okay, so I'm not sure what sound subsystem OpenSUSE uses, but most of them now have GUIs that will let you, say, switch between active headphone ports and speakers as the primary audio device.  Have you tried looking there to see if the special port shows up?

Comment: YaST only shows 1 device to choose. When I try to go to KDE Mixer settings I find a selector for primary output, if I choose headset connector the audio stops working until reboot (if I connect headphones to the **appropriate** hole they work)